# The current httpContext can only be set once during a request Error

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I get this Error **The current httpContext can only be set once during a request.** once in a while on my Umbraco Site (Version 6.0.3). Not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Application pool Managed pipeline Mode from classic to Integrated and this fixed the issue for me. Found it out here : https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/39671-The-current-httpContext-can-only-be-set-once-during-a-request?p=1

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was fixed in 6.1, if you upgrade your installation to this version, it should resolve the issue for you! Details can be seen on the [Issue Tracker](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/OUR-43)